# How do I install my Safari Developer Certificate?

Tags: safari-extension

We develop extensions for Safari. I installed our Safari Developer Certificate on Windows, but I can't install it on mac (we have two certificates). I tried to download and install them from the Apple website but it doesn't work. What do I have to do?

[image: our certificates in the mac]

[image: our certificates in Apple website]

[image: Safari Extension Builder]

Answer (score 1):

When you download the certificate from the web you only get the certificate. The private key is usually on the machine from which you created the certSigningRequest.

The certSigning request (you can create one by using KeyChain Access app) creates the private key and adds it to your login keychain.

If you don't have access to the original machine, then I'd suggest you revoke your certificate on the portal and create a new one.

The only way to export a certificate is to export it along with the private key. Usually folks do this using KeyChain Access app. You can export the p12 format key which can be used to import on a different machine.

Without the private key, downloading the cert from the portal is useless. This is true for not just Safari certs but for all Mac development certs.